# readonly properties is working partially in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, interface

Let's take a look at this code

```js
interface ImmutableValue<T> {
    readonly value: T;
}

let i: ImmutableValue<string> = { value: "hi" };
i.value = "Excellent, I can't change it"; // compile-time error
```

The above is pretty straight forward, we have an interface `ImmutableValue` and since `i` is implementing that interface, `i.value` will be getting compilation error

Now consider the below code

```js
interface Greetable {
  readonly name: string;
}

class Person implements Greetable {
  name: string;

  constructor(n: string) {
    this.name = n;
  }
}

let user1 = new Person('isaac');

user1.name = 'jon'
console.log(user1)
```

For the code above, clearly `Person` is implementing `Greetable` which has a `name` of `readonly` and `user1.name = 'jon'` is a value reassignment and we should get an error. But TS is compiling perfectly fine, any idea why is that?

Comment: Person _extends_ Greetable, including allowing writing to name.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I don't think we can `extends` an interface..

Comment: I don't mean `extends`, I mean in the sense of _adding behaviour_. Anything that expects a Greetable, something that has a readable name property, **can still use Person**. They don't be be able to write through that interface, the fact that another consumer accessing the same value through Person _could_ is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript ignores `readonly` when determining whether two types are compatible, so `Person` is compatible with `Greetable` despite `Greetable` making `name` `readonly` while `Person` doesn't. From [this page on `readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-properties):

> It’s important to manage expectations of what `readonly` implies. It’s useful to signal intent during development time for TypeScript on how an object should be used. **TypeScript doesn’t factor in whether properties on two types are `readonly` when checking whether those types are compatible, so `readonly` properties can also change via aliasing.**

*(my emphasis)*

More generally, though, a subtype can add features on top of its supertype. As [jonrsharpe points out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68690695/readonly-properties-is-working-partially-in-typescript/68690724?noredirect=1#comment121394127_68690695), any code that uses a `Greetable` can still use a `Person`. Code with a `Greetable` reference to `Person` won't be able to change `name` through that reference:

```typescript
function example(g: Greetable) {
    g.name = "example"; // Error
}
example(new Person("Joe"));
```

but being publicly `readonly` doesn't guarantee that something won't change, just that code that has `readonly` access to it can't change it, which is subtly different.

Comment: hmm interesting...my understanding of an `interface` was that, it is to be used to enforce `Person` to have similar signature as `Greetable`. If it's inheritance by `extends`, the part about definition overriding I can understand, but here is nothing to do with inheritance isnt it

Comment: @Isaac - Overriding is related to inheritance, yes, although I think overriding is a bit tangential to this particular aspect and I should probably just reword it out of the answer. :-)